# Device keeps disappearing in DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

I have a droid incredible connected to DDMS, and it shows up, then disappears, then shows up, then disappears, etc.

This makes it impossible to get a heap dump, among other things.

Any idea what is causing this or how to fix it?

=Update =
The thing started to happen again, and it wasn't the USB cable this time. I was able to recreat the problem with 3 different cables, and also two different devices.

Turns out in the most recent case, the ADB was out of date with the Eclipse ADT Tools. Just needed to run the android SDK updater and then kill and restart ADB and things were happy again.

Comment: try `adb kill-server`, unplug your phone, `adb start-server`, plug your phone back in. Also, make sure it's plugged into the USB port connected to the motherboard (on the back), and make sure it's a good USB cable. Also, if this is the first time it's happened, you could try powering your computer and phone off and on. You could get "Remote ADB" from the Market and do it over wi-fi.

Comment: If you use an USB extension cable, try to remove it. I had the same problem and fixed it this way.

Comment: My problem was slightly different from yours, the VZW Galaxy Nexus would disappear from the DDMS only immediately after the app was launched to it.  Replacing the USB cable worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just commonly a problem of broken USB cable. It happens often when you do connect USB cable to phone a lot. I face this always when do the system test.
Change to the new USB cable, it will certainly work!

Comment: The problem turns out to have been the USB port... Its worn out- but looking for a cause with the cable led me to the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This had happened to me when I had not unmounted the phone from the laptop before Switching off the USB storage on the device. Restarting the phone had done the job for me.

You are having a truly "Incredible" "Droid Incredible".